# New c# nullable option

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

In new version of C# is default option nullable. I mean this

[image: Visual Studio project settings where nullable reference types can be enabled and disabled]

It's really good feature for me. But I don't understand one thing. Is property nullable by me or by program?

I know that this property should never be null because I fill it in the form and never set it as null. But in general it can be null. How should I mark it?

Example:

UserModel:

```
public string? Name { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; } = null!
```

I'm really confused.

Comment: *But in general it can be null* - how, when you control the general?

Comment: @CaiusJard Presumably because the class with the `Name` property only has a default constructor (or doesn't initialize `Name` in the constructor). This means that `Name` initially will be null.

Comment: I use the second pattern a lot with Entities or Models.  Basically any class that is used to hold data that is deserialized that cannot use a constructor to pass in the values.  However if you are creating instances of the class directly then the proper way to handle this is to set the property from a constructor, maybe even consider making the class a record.

Comment: @juharr yea i thought the same thing. But this is valid only when is class use correctly. When isn't property can be null..That's why I'm a bit confused and don't know whether to do it by myself or by the "program".

Comment: If this Model is used as the endpoint and you set the value as non-nullable and you did happen to pass a null value it would result in an error.  If you instead allow it to be nullable when in fact it never will be then you have to add a lot of null checking code whenever you need to deference it which kinda defeats the purpose of nullable references.  Also note that a non-nullable reference can in fact still be null.  All this feature does is add attributes that let the compiler know if something is expected to never be null so it can warn you.

Comment: @juharr thank you. Yea i undrestand that it is for compiler. So your recommendation is that if I know the value will not be null I should set it as not null yes?

Comment: And when i write my custom library i think better solution is mark "everything" (model too) what's can be null as null right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that this property should never be null because I fill it in
> the form and never set it as null. But in general it can be null. How
> should I mark it?

If it is set to non-null in the constructor, then you can declare it a `string` rather than `string?` because it really is guaranteed to never be null.

If, however, it is null after the constructor has run (and before any other methods are called) then it CAN be null and you should declare it as `string?`.

The dichotomy you face is that (from what you say) it should never be null when the class is used correctly - i.e. if the calling code does indeed call the method that initialises the property to non-null before accessing it, it will be guaranteed to be not null - which means you would like to declare it as a non-null `string` so that callers don't need to use the null-forgiving `!` operator to suppress nullable warnings.

What to do in this case? Well I think you have three possibilities:

1. Declare the property as nullable: `string?` and let the callers suppress the nullable warning or check the value for null.
2. Initialise the property to a non-null default such as `string.Empty` and declare the property as non nullable `string`.
3. Assume that accessing the property when it is null is a programming error, and throw an appropriate exception.

For the last case, you could do something like this:

```
private string? _name;

public string Name 
{ 
    get
    {
        if (_name == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Do not access Name without setting it to non-null or calling Init()");
            
        return _name;
    }   
    
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value", "You cannot set Name to null.");
            
        _name = value;
    }
}
```

This assumes that there's a method called `Init()` that can be called to initialise `Name`, but of course your code may vary.

Regardless of which of those approaches you take, you should really check for null in the property setter, as shown above.

Note that a more succinct way of writing the setter null check is:

```
set
{
    _name = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("value", "You cannot set Name to null.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand you but what i should use? You answer on my question you can use this or this. And my question was what's better. Thank you

Comment: @PetrKasnal I would use number (3)

Comment: But doing this for every property is a little annoying.

Comment: @PetrKasnal It is extra work to validate parameters, yes. But validating `value` in a setter is no different from validating a non-nullable method parameter. This is why it's better to write immutable classes where the class invariants are established in the constructor and cannot be subsequently violated.

Answer (score 0):

Where a value can be null, and the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` value is set in your `*.csproj` file, *you* must declare those values as nullable.

In your given example, the nullable type (instead of assigning null as a default) is the way to go:

`public string? Name {get; set;}`

You'll also notice VS complaining at you with warnings every time you introduce a property etc which can be nullable, but isn't marked as such.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Ok so it is for program. So only property which is declared in constructor or inline is ok. And another example in Blazor i can inject service like this

[Inject]
private Service Service { get; set; }
And this service visual studio mark as nullable but it cannot be. But should I use it anyway, yes?